# Did the expression "vira e mexe" originate in Brazil? What does it mean precisely?"

Tags: significado, expressões, locuções-adverbias

**IN ENGLISH**

"vira e mexe" is a set phrase defined by [**priberam**](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/vira-e-mexe) as a noun that means *"pessoa que nunca está quieta, que não sossega"* ou *"atividade ou movimentação intensa"*.  The [**senasgent**](http://dicionario.sensagent.com/VIRA%20E%20MEXE/pt-pt/), however, defines it as an adverb meaning "infrequentemente, raramente". That's not what I hear in Brazil. "vira e mexe" here will inevitably mean "every now and then".

Examples:

- "É muito ruim trabalhar ao lado dele; vira e mexe ele vem me perguntar alguma coisa."
- "Vira e mexe ele está a arrumar confusão com alguém."
- "Esse casamento não vai dar certo; vira e mexe eles estão brigando."

Although I'm sure of its meaning (frequentemente, repetidamente) when I hear it from my folks, my question is "does anyone use this expression to mean "raramente"? Was it brought to Brazil by the Portuguese or is it a Brazilian expression?

**IN PORTUGUESE**

A expressão "vira e mexe" é descrita no [**priberam**](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/vira-e-mexe) como um substantivo de dois gêneros e dois números, significando *"pessoa que nunca está quieta, que não sossega"* ou *"atividade ou movimentação intensa"*. Já o [**senasgent**](http://dicionario.sensagent.com/VIRA%20E%20MEXE/pt-pt/) define como um advérbio que significa "raramente, infrequentemente". O uso que observo com mais frequência no Brasil, no entanto, é como locução adverbial, mas no sentido de "frequentemente, repetidamente".
Exemplos:

- "É muito ruim trabalhar ao lado dele; vira e mexe ele vem me perguntar alguma coisa."
- "Vira e mexe ele está a arrumar confusão com alguém."
- "Esse casamento não vai dar certo; vira e mexe eles estão brigando."

Embora eu tenha a certeza do significado de "frequentemente" quando ouço a expressão dita por meus pares, a minha pergunta é: "alguém usa "vira e mexe" com o significado de raramente?  A expressão teve sua origem em Portugal e foi trazida para o Brasil, ou é "coisa nossa"?

Comment: @Centaurus: Vê o link da senasgent outra vez: diz frequentemente também!

Comment: @Jacinto  You're right.  I missed the definition at the top.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**PORTUGUÊS**

Numa pesquisa pela net encontrei ***vira e mexe*** usado com dois significados diferentes. Estes dois significados aparecem no Aulete digital, mas em sítios diferentes:

> [Em ***virar*** — vira e mexe](http://www.aulete.com.br/virar) A toda hora, sem mais nem menos: *Vira e mexe ele volta ao assunto*
>
> [Em ***vira e mexe***](http://www.aulete.com.br/vira%20e%20mexe) [Brasil] (1) Pessoa agitada, irrequieta; VIRA-MEXE. (2) Correria, Azáfama.

O significado de *a toda a hora* é o conhecido pelo Centaurus e encontra-se em imensos livros publicados recentemente, todos no Brasil. Com o significado de *correria, azáfama*, encontrei só duas ocorrências, com a ajuda deste [Corpus do Português](http://corpus.byu.edu/), ambas também no Brasil:

> [É], eu gosto de passear mas — que eu saia com aquela responsabilidade, quer dizer, pra — comprar — pacote — e não sei quê — e paga — e tira e ***vira e mexe*** e confere e procura eu não suporto. (Recife, data desconhecida.)
>
> Procurava disfarçar as apreensões, arrumando os trastes do quarto, mexendo nos baús, numa inquietação crescente, num ***vira-e-mexe*** cada vez mais açodado, abrindo e fechando gavetas, ata­rantada, com o coração aos pulos. ([Adolfo Caminha](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolfo_Caminha), [*A Normalista*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Normalista), 1893.)

Foi a primeira vez que encontrei esta expressão. Isto com o facto de todas as ocorrências serem no Brasil leva-me a crer que se trata duma expressão cunhada no Brasil. Uma expressão que se usa em Portugal com o mesmo sentido, também usada no Brasil, é *volta e meia*.

**ENGLISH**

Searching the net I found ***vira e mexe*** (turn and move/handle) being used with two different meanings. Both appear in Aulete digital, but under different entries:

> [In ***virar*** — vira e mexe](http://www.aulete.com.br/virar) A toda hora, sem mais nem menos: *Vira e mexe ele volta ao assunto*. (All the time, without reason. *Vira e mexe he insists on the subject*.)
>
> [In ***vira e mexe***](http://www.aulete.com.br/vira%20e%20mexe) [Brazil] (1) Pessoa agitada, irrequieta; VIRA-MEXE (agitated, restive person. (2) Correria, Azáfama (bustle).

The meaning *all the time* is the one known to Centaurus and can be found in many recently published books, all in Brazil. I found two occurrences only with the meaning of *bustle*, in this [Portuguese Corpus](http://corpus.byu.edu/), both in Brazil too:

> [É], eu gosto de passear mas — que eu saia com aquela responsabilidade, quer dizer, pra — comprar — pacote — e não sei quê — e paga — e tira e ***vira e mexe*** e confere e procura eu não suporto. (Yes, I enjoy walking in the streets, but — to go out with that responsibility, I mean, to — buy — packs — and what not — and pay — and pick up and ***vira e mexe*** [turn and handle] and check and search, I can’t stand that.
>
> Procurava disfarçar as apreensões, arrumando os trastes do quarto, mexendo nos baús, numa inquietação crescente, num ***vira-e-mexe*** cada vez mais açodado, abrindo e fechando gavetas, ata­rantada, com o coração aos pulos. ([Adolfo Caminha](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolfo_Caminha), [*A Normalista*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Normalista), 1893.)

It was the first time I, born and bred in Portugal, ever encountered this phrase. This together with the fact that all occurrences I found were in brazil leads me to believe the phrase was coined in Brazil. The phrase used in Portugal with the same meaning, also used in Brazil, is *volta e meia* (one and half turns.)

Comment: Também usamos "volta e meia" com o mesmo significado.

Comment: Obrigado. Estava mesmo com essa dúvida. Mais um edit.

Comment: @Centaurus Vendo bem, a citação do Recife está de acordo com a definição no Priberam.